# Почему зависает цикл?

Tags: java, android

Захотелось сделать программу, которая бы быстро считала текст от 0 до огромного числа. Как я только не пробовал это сделать - не получается. Первый вариант был без вывода числа на экран и без Thread.Sleep и он работал, но всё же чтобы всё происходило плавно и прозрачно.

```
public void button2(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        TextView textbody1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4); //почему-то activity крашится, если прописать эту строку там же, где и переменные
        do
        {   count ++; //переменные типа int объявлены в шапке класса
            countlast = count+5;
            textbody1.setText("Число равно:"+count);
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(150);}
        while (count < countlast);
```

Пробовал и с меньшими числами, и без бесконечного цикла - результат один: программа зависает и на эмуляторе и на железном девайсе.

Да, я понимаю, что я наверное где-то сильно накосячил, но я только учусь, а учиться я, к сожалению, могу только на практике, иначе ничего не запомню.

Вроде должна отвисать и обновлять textview, но зависает при нажатии кнопки, а по логам Android Studio в этот раз ничего не могу понять, кроме того, что она ест слишком много ресурсов.
Наверняка есть какой-то менее извращенный способ выполнения этой простой задачки.

Comment: У вас цикл крутится в главном потоке, соответственно пока он не закончится UI обновляться не сможет так как он это тоже делает в главном потоке, а вы его окупировали своим циклом.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш цикл будет работать вечно по той причине, что условие будет выполняться всегда:

```
count < countlast
```

`count` всегда будет меньше, чем `countlast` на 5 из за этой строки:

```
countlast = count+5;
```

Comment: Это сделано специально. Проблема в том, что текст в textview не меняется во время выполнения цикла.

Comment: @user3807779, это потому, что вы выполняете цикл в основном потоке, а т. к. обновление UI происходит так же в основном потоке, то TextVIew обновится только после выполнения кода из основного потока. Если хотите, чтобы обновлялось, вынесите цикл во второстепенный поток, и только TextView обновляйте в главном отоке

Answer (score 3):

Что бы не блокировать основной поток и тем самым не блокировать интерфейс приложения надо как то так:

```
public void button2(final View view) throws InterruptedException {
        final TextView textbody1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        // кладем в очередь исполнения следующий код:
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                count++;
                countlast = count + 5;
                textbody1.setText("Число равно:" + count);
                if (count < countlast) {
                    // если условие выполняется опять кладем наш Runnable в очередь
                    view.postDelayed(this, 150);
                }
            }
        }, 150);
}
```

Comment: Я нуб, а вы мне код с ошибками даёте. Среда ругается на синтаксис postDelayed. Я не дорос пока до уровня понимания этого кода.

Comment: Ох, давно код без лямбд не писал, совсем с ретролямбдой расслабился, начал синтаксис анонимных классов забывать. А запускать андройд студию у меня сейчас возможности нет, так что уж извините по памяти пишу. Исправил вроде.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дык он вроде основы и пытается учить, только пример не очень удачный для приложения с визуальным интерфейсом выбрал, циклы с вычислениями это Hello World для консольных приложений.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш цикл никогда не завершится, это вам известно?

Проблема в том, что программа жрет cpu, молотя операции в цикле, т.к. в метод `sleep` передается значение в миллисекундах, а 150 это слишком мало. Попробуйте хотя бы 1000 - 1 секунда.